# How to set method to call of usercontrol link

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've created a user control that displays the header (not < head >, I mean the title, datetime page is created and so on) on each page on my website. In that user control I also have one link. A link that will be displayed on the page `IF (user = admin)`.

Currently this link is a pure link, and I have no problems to change the "navigateUrl" to the correct value for each page. (Each page includes this user control, and from each page I set the value for navigateUrl.)

But!

On some of my pages I use a linkbutton instead of a hyperlink. But then I have to add that linkbutton from the page.aspx instead of usercontrol.ascx

My problem is that, I want to change the hyperlink in my user control to a linkbutton instead, so I can call methods with that link. (Method is on page.aspx, not within the user control).

What method to call differ from page to page, so I want to set which method to call each time I include the user control.

If I have inside my user control

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

And for now I set values within the usercontrol by:

```
 mainPageHeader1.headTitle = "text";
```

How do I set what method to call for the linkbutton?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In the markup of your UserControl, specify the handler for the click event

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="LinkButton1_Clicked" runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" />
```

Declare a custom event in your usercontrol

```
public class MyUserControl
{
   public event System.EventHandler LinkButtonClicked;


   //add handler for your LinkButton
   protected void LinkButton1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Raise your custom event here that can be handled in any page that use your control
      LinkButtonClicked(sender, e);
   }
}
```

In your page.aspx, add handler for your custom event

```
protected void MyUserControl2_LinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //handle the event here
}
```

**Update**

In your page where you add your control,

```
<custom:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl2" runat="server"     
                      LinkButtonClicked="MyUserControl_LinkButtonClicked" />
```

That's all

**Update**

Subscribing for the event in code-behind did the work. I have not figured out why it  didn't work from the markup.

From the Page_Load of the page in which the UserControl is, do this

```
 MyUserControl2.LinkButtonClicked += new EventHandler(MyUserControl_LinkButtonClicked);
```

and it should work.

Checks to see if the event has been subscribed to Either codebehind (`eventhandler += EventHandler(sender, e)` or the aspx markup `OnClick="EventHandlerMethodName"`) - [this would be null if it wasn't subscribed to somewhere](http://forums.asp.net/t/1543851.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how this will work. If I declare the "linkbutton_clicked" in usercontrol, and "myusercontrol_linkbutton_clicked" inside page.aspx.c. Is everything going to work?? Or is there anything I have to "set" at page creation? I understand that I inside myusercontrol_linkbuttonClicked have to call the method I want to execute.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: I got this error: System.NullReferenceException, on "LinkbuttonClicked(sender,e)"

Comment: @Mattias You get `System.NullReferenceException` if the event hasn't been subscribed to - either from Markup or Codebehind. It's not working with the Markup for some reason but it worked with code-behind. See my last update